# PHP how to make URL something like product.php?id=1

Tags: php

I am doing a simple php cart. Basically is for learning purpose and I am trying to search solution for my question. However, i am not sure what is the keyword for my question. Hence, I post it here.

```
echo "<p>Product A | <a href='product.php?id=a'>Add to Cart</a></p>";
echo "<p>Product B | <a href='product.php?id=b'>Add to Cart</a></p>";
echo "<p>Product C | <a href='product.php?id=c'>Add to Cart</a></p>";
```

Basically, every product shares the same landing page -> product.php  just like normal shopping cart.  So when user clicks product A "Add to Cart", it will land on produt.php?id=a , if product B, then will be produt.php?id=b  . My questions is how to make the url sth like I mentioned?

Please refer to a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: And your exact question is?

Comment: i have edited the question. plz check

Comment: I think you mean that you don't exactly know how to get the id from a database?

Comment: @SuperDJ sorry that my question is not clear enough. I have added a screenshot for us to understand it easier.

Comment: I still don't get it. Where is the problem? "how to make the url sth like I mentioned?" -You already answered that question by posting the URL. The URL is nothing but the string that appears in the browser's address bar and which is evaluated later on the server. Are you having problems with generating the URL strings or generating the resulting pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `id` parameter is in the url it is called a `GET` parameter. You can access to GET parameters using the global variable `$_GET`.

In `product.php` you should have something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if($id=='a'){
        // do something
    }
    else if($id=='b'){
        // do something else
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do note that it's better to first escape the `$_GET['id']` before doing anything with it

Comment: Yes probably I just edited ;-) I'm not even sure if it answers to the OP's question ...

Comment: What I exactly ment is set it to `(int)` so even if someone else made tekst of the id it wouldn't work. Second check if the id exists in the database to make sure people don't get to see an empty page. Besides typecasting to an int you can do more.

Comment: @A.Omar sorry that my question is not clear enough. I have added a screenshot for us to understand it easier. the screenshot is exactly what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
// Show all products
$q = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT `id` FROM `products`" );
if( mysqli_num_rows( $q ) > 0 ) { // Check if there are results
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $q ) ) {
        echo '<p>Product A | <a href="product.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Add to Cart</a></p>';
    }
}
```

In `product.php`

```
function productExists( $id ) {
    if( !empty( $id ) ) {
        $q = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT `id` FROM `products` WHERE `id` = $id");

        if( mysqli_num_rows( $q ) > 0 ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function productData( $id ) {
    if( !empty( $id ) ) {
        $q = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT `id`, `product_name`, `product_price`, `product_quantity`, `product_image` FROM `products` WHERE `id` = $id");

        if( mysqli_num_rows( $q ) > 0 ) {
            $data = array(); // Store data
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $q ) ) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            if( !empty( $data ) ) { // Make sure all data is gathered before proceeding
                return $data;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if( !empty( $_GET['id'] ) ) { // empty does the same as isset() but also checks if the value is not empty
    $id = (int)mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $_GET['id'] );

    if( productExists( $id ) ) {
        $data = productData( $id );

        echo 'Product: '.$data['product_name']; // Etc.
    } else {
        echo 'Product doesn\'t exists';
    }
}
```

When adjusting some of the code you're also able to get the other columns

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    if(is_numeric($_GET['id']))
    {
       $id = $_GET['id'];
        if($id=='a')
       {

       }
       else if($id=='b')
      {
        // do something else
      }else
     {
       echo "product does not exists";
     }

   }
   else{
   echo "product does not exists";
   }



}else
{
   echo "product does not exists";     
}
```

Comment: sorry that my question is not clear enough. I have added a screenshot for us to understand it easier. the screenshot is exactly what i want to achieve.